# Bootstrap 4 Align Text in block under the image on different row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this layout and while its what i want, I want the text in the row under the image to be aligned directly under it in a block.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-5">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="mx-auto d-block" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://placeimg.com/252/191/arch" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="text-justify  g-mt-50">
                    To create an interior, the designer must develop an overall concept and stick to it.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">                
                    <p class="text-justify g-mt-50">
                        Design is not just what it looks like and feels like. Design is how it works.
                    </p>                   
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img class="mx-auto d-block" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://placeimg.com/252/191/arch" />
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img  class="mx-auto d-block" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://placeimg.com/252/191/arch" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="text-justify g-mt-50">
                    For a house to be successful, the objects in it must communicate with one another, respond and balance one another.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="text-justify g-mt-50">
                    All rooms ought to look as if they were lived in, and to have so to say, a friendly welcome ready for the incomer.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img  class="mx-auto d-block" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://placeimg.com/252/191/arch" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I managed to get the desired layout below. I inserted another div with the styling like below but this is not very responsive. How can i achieve my layout and make it responsive using Bootstrap 4?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-5">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="mx-auto d-block" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://placeimg.com/252/191/arch" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6"> 
                <div class="col-md-5 text-center" style="margin-left:180px">
                    <p class="text-justify  g-mt-50">
                        To create an interior, the designer must develop an overall concept and stick to it.
                    </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-5 text-center" style="margin-left:180px">
                    <p class="text-justify ml-50 g-mt-50">
                        Design is not just what it looks like and feels like. Design is how it works.
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img class="mx-auto d-block" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://placeimg.com/252/191/arch" />
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img  class="mx-auto d-block" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://placeimg.com/252/191/arch" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-5 text-center" style="margin-left:180px">
                    <p class="text-justify g-mt-50">
                        For a house to be successful, the objects in it must communicate with one another, respond and balance one another.
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-5 text-center" style="margin-left:180px">
                    <p class="text-justify g-mt-50">
                        All rooms ought to look as if they were lived in, and to have so to say, a friendly welcome ready for the incomer.
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img class="mx-auto d-block" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://placeimg.com/252/191/arch" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you actually want to achieve. If all you want is your text to be below the image, why are you placing it in separate columns and in separate rows?  Why over-complicate the Grid layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I managed to understand you correctly, then the following is the layout you want. That layout is fully responsive and is achieved by using these classes for your text columns:

`col-10 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 px-0 px-xl-4 mx-auto`

The `col-*` classes manage the column width at different screen sizes and the `px-*` classes manage the horizontal padding while `mx-auto` centers the columns horizontally.

Here's the working code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="mx-auto d-block" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://placeimg.com/252/191/arch" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 px-0 px-xl-4 mx-auto">
            <p class="text-justify g-mt-50">
                To create an interior, the designer must develop an overall concept and stick to it.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 px-0 px-xl-4 mx-auto">                
            <p class="text-justify g-mt-50">
                Design is not just what it looks like and feels like. Design is how it works.
            </p>                   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="mx-auto d-block" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://placeimg.com/252/191/arch" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img  class="mx-auto d-block" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://placeimg.com/252/191/arch" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 px-0 px-xl-4 mx-auto">
            <p class="text-justify g-mt-50">
                For a house to be successful, the objects in it must communicate with one another, respond and balance one another.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 px-0 px-xl-4 mx-auto">
            <p class="text-justify g-mt-50">
                All rooms ought to look as if they were lived in, and to have so to say, a friendly welcome ready for the incomer.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img  class="mx-auto d-block" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://placeimg.com/252/191/arch" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```